# g++ compiler absent in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, g++

When I tried to compile a c++ program in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it said:

```
The program g++ is currently not installed but this package is not available
```

I also checked in `/user/bin/` there was no file named as g++ or g++-4.8. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is in the [`build-essential`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/build-essential) package

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```